# Parse Promise not working for Parse.Cloud.run() method

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, synchronous

I am trying to use Parse Promises for Parse.Cloud.run() method but it is not giving any output.The code is working for save method

## Working

```
var RoomObj = Parse.Object.extend("Room");

var obj = new RoomObj();

obj.save({ "demo":123 }).then(
  function(object) {
    // the object was saved.
    console.log("PRomise worked");
  },
  function(error) {
    // saving the object failed.
           console.log("PRomise error");
  });
```

## Not Working

```
Parse.Cloud.run("checkRoomsForAvailableBookingTime", {"bookfromtime":bookfromtime,"booktotime":booktotime, "mac_id":mac_id}, {}).then(
function(object) {
    console.log("Result object is : " + object);
},
function(error) {
    console.log("Result error is : " + error.message + error.code);
});//then block
```

==============================
checkRoomsForAvailableBookingTime method

Parse.Cloud.define("checkRoomsForAvailableBookingTime", function(request, response) {

```
               var BookingObj = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");

               var bookingQuery= new Parse.Query(BookingObj);

               var flag;


               var bookfromtime = request.params.bookfromtime;
               var booktotime   = request.params.booktotime;
               var mac_id       = request.params.mac_id;    

               var starttimeArray = [];
               var endtimeArray = [];

               var currentDate = new Date();
               var todayDate = currentDate.getDate() +'-' + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' +
               currentDate.getFullYear();

               bookingQuery.equalTo("book_date",todayDate);
               bookingQuery.equalTo("room_mac_id",mac_id);

               bookingQuery.ascending("book_fromtime");

               bookingQuery.find({

                          success: function(results) {

                              console.log("TOTAL BOOKINGS :" + results.length);

                                for(var i=0 ; i< results.length;i++)
                                {

                                    starttimeArray[i] = results[i].get('book_fromtime');
                                    endtimeArray[i]   = results[i].get('book_totime');      
                                }//for loop

                                var startAndEndArray={
                                    "start":starttimeArray,
                                    "end":endtimeArray
                                };


                            if(results.length == 0)
                            {
                                // console.log("No booking is done for today so you can book the room");
                                 // return true; 
                                 flag = true;

                            }  //if block

                            else if(results.length == 1 )
                            {

                                    if(bookfromtime < starttimeArray[0] && booktotime <= starttimeArray[0])
                                    {
                                         // console.log("You can book rooom"); 
                                         // return true;
                                         flag = true;
                                    }

                                    else if(bookfromtime >= endtimeArray[0])
                                    {
                                        // console.log("You can book rooom"); 
                                        // return true;
                                        flag = true;

                                    } 

                                    else 
                                    {
                                      // console.log("CANNOT BOOK ROOM");
                                      // return false;
                                      flag = false;

                                    }

                            } //else if block

                            else if(bookfromtime < starttimeArray[0] && booktotime <= starttimeArray[0]){

                              // console.log("You can book rooom"); 
                              // return true;
                              flag = true;

                            }

                            else if(bookfromtime >= endtimeArray[results.length -1] )
                            {
                              // console.log("You can book rooom");  
                              // return true;
                              flag = true;

                            }

                            else
                            {       
                                    console.log("IN ELSE BLOCK");  

                                    for(var counter=0 ; counter < results.length ;counter++)
                                    {

                                        if(bookfromtime > starttimeArray[counter] && bookfromtime <=  starttimeArray[counter+1])
                                        { 

                                              // console.log("First if");

                                             if(bookfromtime >= endtimeArray[counter] && booktotime <= starttimeArray[counter+1])
                                             {      
                                                 // console.log("You can book the room");
                                                 // return true;
                                                 flag = true;

                                             }//if block 

                                        }//if block

                                    }//for loop block

                                    // console.log("CANNOT BOOK ROOM");
                                    // return false;
                                    flag = false;

                            } //outer else block


                              response.success(flag);
                          },
                          error: function(error) {

                          response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

                          }

                 });//find block

               //query.notContainedIn("user_id",userArray);

               });//function block
```

can anybody help me what is the issue ? Thanks.

Comment: where is `checkRoomsForAvailableBookingTime` defined? show its code

Comment: @wain i have added code please check it and please  let me know what is the issue. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Just a reminder parse.com is shutting down. You might not want to use it anymore...

Comment: at the end, the 'sucess' or  'error' needs prefix to wrap it as promise.... https://parse.com/questions/not-waiting-for-cloud-code-callbackspromises

Comment: Yes i read it is hutting down Thanks for telling anyways.                                          I did not understand @RobertRowntree.  Could you please explain a little bit ? what changes should i make in above code? Thanks.